# Como puedo solucionar error funcion no definida en App.js (React js)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Esta es la estructura de mi App.js

```
    import Cabecera from './components/Cabecera'
    import './App.css';
    
    function App() {
      manejaClick = () => {
        console.log('He sido clickeado!');
      }
      const miau = 'Bienvenido miau'
      return (
    <div className="App">
      <Cabecera miau={miau} manejaClick={this.manejaClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Pero arroja el siguiente error

```
src\App.js
  Line 5:3:  'manejaClick' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Esta es la url del repo https://github.com/kikedb/hello-world/blob/main/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás mezclando un componente de clase con un componente funcional ([info](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)).

En el código de tu pregunta tienes un componente funcional pero estás haciendo referencia a `this` que se usa en los componentes de clase para hacer referencia al propio componente. De ahí que te diga que no encuentra la función `manejaClick` porque `this` es `undefined` en un componente funcional.

Dicho código te funcionaría simplemente quitando el `this.` de `manejaClick={this.manejaClick}` y definiendo la función `manejaClick` como:

```
const manejaClick = () => {
        console.log('He sido clickeado!');
      }
```

Dicho lo cual. Te desaconsejo que utilices los componentes de clase. El equipo de React hace tiempo que apostó por los componentes funcionales utilizando los [Hooks](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) para el manejo de estados (entiendo que llegarás pronto a los estados). Por lo que deberías quedarte con tu primer código con las modificaciones que te he comentado.

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaracion, ahora entiendo porque ambas declaraciones son distintas

Comment: De nada. Un buen ejercicio es cambiar tu código actual del repositorio y pasar los componentes de clase a funcionales.

Answer (score 0):

Averiguando tube que cambiar la estructura del componente App.js dejandolo de la siguiente manera

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cabecera from './components/Cabecera'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  manejaClick = () => {
    console.log('He sido clickeado!');
  }
  render () {
    const miau = 'Bienvenido miau'
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Cabecera miau={miau} manejaClick={this.manejaClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

y funciono, pero no entiendo mucho la razon ya que soy nuevo en react, si es que alguien podria explicarmelo seria genial.
Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

prueba:

```
manejaClick () {
    console.log('He sido clickeado!');
}
```

y es this.manejaClick()

Comment: Una explicación no estaría de más. ¿Qué error cometió el OP?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, intente con lo que me indicas pero me arroja un error Unexpected token, expected ";" (5:17)

Comment: Candid Moe que significa OP ?

Comment: depende de como de la herramienta del build ,aveces rechaza ese tipo de escritura ,por q es una redundancia o innecesaria , no con todas los build pero si a veces. aparte falto la llamada a la funcion " () "

Comment: @WillMend "OP" viene del sitio en inglés, es para el _Original Publisher_. Como quien dice, el que puso la pregunta e inició el hilo